# What introductory textbook material should one read before getting started on learning PCA and high-dimensional clustering?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

I've taken some introductory statistics course in uni but not high level multivariate analysis, I also have a minor in math if that helps with the recommendation. I feel like I should go over some chapters in a standard multivariate analysis textbook so I'm not completely lost when I try to learn about high-dimensional clustering and non-linear reduction. But because of how little experience I have on this topic, I want to get some advice on this. What introductory textbook material (specifically chapters) should I read and grasp first before jumping into high-dimensional clustering analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mathematical prerequisites try:

- Carl D. Meyer, Matrix analysis and applied linear algebra.

For multivariate statistics:

- Mardia, Kent and Bibby, Multivariate Analysis.

Comment: Are there specific chapters that I should pay more attention to specifically for my purpose?

Comment: It depends on your knowledge... I would suggest you start with the Appendix A in Mardia for the Linear Algebra background. Keep the Meyer next to you, and in case you have any doubts you can check in the book by Meyer. Then go for Chapter 8 and 13 in Mardia.

Comment: @lucusk If you find the answer useful, please vote it or accept it. Thanks :-)

Comment: I'm going to get the book tomorrow from my school's library and I'll vote it after I take a look.